# GoogleAccountCredential + Google Play Services + Refresh Token - how this works together?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I have published a pretty successful app about 2 weeks ago. But starting from yesterday, users keep sending me emails about Drive not being accessable anymore. After a quick debug, I found that requests to the Drive API now return "403 Forbidden" -> "Access Not Configured".

I think this might be an issue with the refresh token not being handled properly.

I'm using the following code (from the Android Drive SDK samples):

```
mCredentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
String accountName = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(PREF_DRIVE_NAME, null);
if (accountName != null) {
     setupDrive(accountName);
} else {
     startActivityForResult(mCredentials.newChooseAccountIntent(), 0);
}
```

`setupDrive(...)` looks like this:

```
 mCredentials.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
 try {
        mCredentials.getToken();
 } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(AbstractDriveActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Error getting auth token", e);
        if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
              Intent intent = ((UserRecoverableAuthException) e).getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        startActivity(intent);
        } else {
               Toast.makeText(AbstractDriveActivity.this, getString(R.string.toast_drive_setup_error),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               finish();
        }
  }
  drive = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(),
                    mCredentials).build();
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

From my understanding, `GoogleAccountCredential` uses the Google Play Services to manage the OAuth2 flow and all you need to provide is the username. Am I wrong? Did I miss something?

Btw: After clearing app data, selecting the Google Account again, everything works fine. That's why I think that it has something to do with the refresh token.

Goddchen

Answer (score 1):

No guaranty, but the problem might come from here:

```
mCredentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

This method appears as deprecated to me. You should upgrade your SDK and environment and change it to:

```
mCredentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
```